# How to read SQL Server 2008 date into Java using JPA

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, hibernate, jpa, apache-axis

I need to use java.util.Calendar in order for Axis2 webservice client to send/receive Date objects.  So in my JPA model object I changed all java.sql.Date into java.util.Calendar.  By using java.util.Calendar the Axis2 webservice part work ok.

I'm able to save a java.util.Calendar object into database.  Problem is that I can not read the object back from database!!!

When I try to read a saved object from SQL Server 2008 I get this error:

```
An error occurred while converting the nvarchar value to JDBC data type TIMESTAMP.
```

In database the date field where it fails to read is of type "date".  Also if in database I change the date field to type "datetime" it works ok, but I to use the "date" type.  Anyone has any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So in my JPA model object I changed all java.sql.Date into java.util.Calendar.

Using a `java.sql.Date` in your domain objects is not really a good idea anyway.

> In database the date field where it fails to read is of type "date". Also if in database I change the date field to type "datetime" it works ok, but I to use the "date" type. Anyone has any clues on how to fix this?

Maybe your `Calendar` is not annotated properly, change it like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) 
private java.util.Calendar someDate;
```

Below, the relevant section from the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 9.1.20 Temporal Annotation
>
> The Temporal annotation must be
>   specified for persistent fields or
>   properties of type `java.util.Date`
>   and `java.util.Calendar`. It may only
>   be specified for fields or properties
>   of these types.
>
> The `Temporal` annotation may be used
>   in conjunction with the `Basic`
>   annotation.
>
> The `TemporalType` enum defines the
>   mapping for these temporal types.
>
> ```
> public enum TemporalType {
>     DATE, //java.sql.Date
>     TIME, //java.sql.Time
>     TIMESTAMP //java.sql.Timestamp
> }
> ```
>
> ...

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 9.1.20 "Temporal Annotation"

Comment: I didn't know about that Calendar annotation. Thanks.

Comment: @Marquinio You're welcome. But it's not a calendar specific annotation. I'll add a reference to the spec.

Comment: Not useful for Jpa 2.0 and MS SQL Server 2012. Temporal type DATE is not recognized.